# How can i only return name string for each key in Json doc?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i am using the following code to get a key's from a json doc to build a class.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log([keys[i]]);
}
```

and the output looks similar to this

```
[ 'address' ]
[ 'Owner Name:' ]
[ 'Mail Owner Name:' ]
[ 'Mailing Address:' ]
[ 'Tax Billing City State:' ]
[ 'Tax Billing Zip:' ]
[ 'Tax Billing Zip+4:' ]
```

is there a way to return only the actual string value with out brackets or do i have to go and remove them before i output each line ?

Comment: `console.log(keys[i])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the brackets [] inside console.log().

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(keys[i]);
}
```

Otherwise you are creating arrays of one element each (keys[i]) and therefore the output you got

Answer (score 0):

You have placed square brackets around `keys[i]` in your `console.log`. Remove these brackets like so...

```
var obj = JSON.parse(result);
var keys = Object.keys(obj);
for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
  console.log(keys[i]);
}
```

...to get the result...

```
'address'
'Owner Name:'
'Mail Owner Name:'
'Mailing Address:'
'Tax Billing City State:'
'Tax Billing Zip:'
'Tax Billing Zip+4:'
```